# Is there a way to make a page rendered with getServerSideProps non-blocking so it partially renders before getServerSideProps completes?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, fetch-api

I have a very simple component that fetches users from an Next api. I am trying to move the fetch from the client to the server using getServerSideProps but I cant see how to do so in a non-blocking way.

This is /api/users. Its a simple call to a mock API to retrieve dummy users wrapped in a delay.

```
export default function handler (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    (async () => {
      let value = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      let result = await value.json();
      let data = result.slice(0,2);
      console.log("API fetch result", JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
      res.status(200).json(data);
    })()
  }, 5000);  
}
```

This a component to fetch the data

```
export const Users = () => {
    let [users, setUsers] = useState();

    useEffect(()=>{
        (async () => {
            let value = await fetch("/api/users");
            let result = await value.json();
            setUsers(result);
        })()
    }, []);

    return <div>
            <h1>header</h1>
            {!users && <p>loading users</p>}
            {users && 
             <p className="fade-in">
               users: <pre>{JSON.stringify(users, null, 4)}</pre>
             </p>
            }
            <h2>footer</h2>
    </div>
}
```

If I move the fetch call to getServerSideProps and pass the users to the component, the component doesnt render until the delayed API call has completed. This does not delay component rendering when the fetch is done on the client but its unacceptable to delay rendering of the component while waiting for data to load in getServerSideProps.

This is the modified Users component with getServerSideProps included. It doesnt render until getServerSideProps returns so there doesnt appear to be a way to partially render elements within the component while waiting for server side props.

```
export const UsersFromServer = (props) => {

    return <div>
            <h1>header</h1>
            {!users && <p>loading users</p>}
            {users && 
             <p className="fade-in">
               users: <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.result, null, 4)}</pre>
             </p>
            }
            <h2>footer</h2>
    </div>
}

// the delayed fetch has been moved to the server
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    let { params, req, res, query } = context;
    let value = await fetch(host + "/api/users");
    let result = value.json();

    console.log("getServerSideProps called on the server", params, req, res, query)
    return {
      props: result
    }
 }
```

I am new to Next js so Im not sure if Im just approaching this in the wrong way. Is there a way to use getServerSideProps in a non-blocking way to allow partial render of UsersFromServer before the (delayed) fetch is completed?

The documentation [here][1] says

```
getServerSideProps should return an object with:

*props - An optional object with the props that will be received by the page component. It should be a serializable object or a Promise that resolves to a serializable object.*
```

I tried recoding getServerSideProps to return a promise but this results in an error.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    let { params, req, res, query } = context;

    // let value = await fetch(host + "/api/users");
    // let result = await value.json();
    // console.log("getServerSideProps called on the server", params, req, res, query)
    // return {
    //   props: {result}
    // }

    let propsPromise = fetch(host + "/api/users").then((value)=>{
        value.json().then((result)=>{
            return {
                props: {result}
            }          
        })
    })
    return {props: propsPromise};
  }
```

error:

```
Server Error
Error: Error serializing props returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/ssr".
Reason: Props must be returned as a plain object from getServerSideProps: `{ props: { ... } }` (received: `[object Undefined]`).
```

Comment: You can't do this easily with `getServerSideProps`. To render a page/component server side, all data must be known. Use `getServerSideProps`, if the delay/response time is acceptable. Otherwise use `getStaticProps` with client side fetch. **Disclaimer:** I'm new to next.js too. That's what I understand after completing the [Basic Learning Path](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, but by adding a loader in _app.js , you can fix the issue.

Comment: Hi interesting solution do you have an example you can share.